Is the Hodge dual operation metric independent?
I'm trying to find out if the Hodge star operation is metric-independent, and I've come across two definitions of it.
One, from Wikipedia, states that you can define it by the property
$$\alpha \wedge ({\star} \beta) = \langle \alpha,\beta \rangle \,\omega \text{ for all }''k''-\text{vectors } \alpha,\beta\in {\textstyle\bigwedge}^{\!k}V $$
Which is clearly metric-dependent from the appearance of $\langle \alpha,\beta \rangle$ on the right-hand side.
The second definition, I found it here and states that it can be defined by the property
$$\omega \wedge \star \omega=d x_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge d x_n$$
which seems metric-independent to me.
Which one is it? Is the metric hidden somewhere in the second definition?

Your quote of the second is missing a huge detail and is very misleading. We are working with an orthonormal basis of the $1$-forms when we define the $k$-form $\omega$ there. So yes, very much metric dependent.

It does in fact depend on the metric and the Wikipedia definition is more general.
In the second source, they are working on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and have implicitly chosen the normalized Euclidean metric so that $\langle \omega, \omega\rangle = \det(\langle dx_i, dx_j \rangle)_{i,j=1}^k) = 1$.
